# Resharper: code issues only in cs files

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, resharper

When I use "Code issue in solution" all get all code issues in all solution. In cs, cshtml, js etc file.
How can check code issues only in *.cs files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/26/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/)

May be this will help you.